# Move database from SQL 7 to 2005 / 2008

Tags: sql-server, migration

I have several pretty large databases located in a SQL Server 7 box. Whats the best way to get them into SQL Server 2008? As far as I know, there were changes to the underlying file structures so I am not sure that a simple detach/attach would work.

When I tried attaching from 2008 it complained strongly. "Version no longer supported" etc etc.  What options do I have? Are there any tools on the market that can connect to both 7 and 2008 and then move the schema and data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to attach them to a SQL 2000 or SQL 2005 instance first, then attach them to a SQL 2008 instance.  There's no direct upgrade path from SQL 7 to SQL 2008.

Comment: +1 yeah, a LITTLE too old for direct upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you do this with a backup, script your DB creations, and then apply those in the new server?